# Android, Eclipse - I don't have NoTitleBar Theme, how to download it?

Tags: android, eclipse, download, titlebar

I've downloaded package with Ecpise, SDK and Java included, it didn't have much themes or utilities, but now I found out that it is still putting the TitleBar to my apps. I want to get rid of it, but `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` in Android Manifest doesn't seem to be working. How can I download this and other styles please?

EDIT: Even this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in method onCreate() doesn't work.

EDIT2:
Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jakubturcovsky.workoutapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:name=".Polodrepy"
            android:exported="false" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Picture of what I want to get rid of:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuXbQ.jpg

Comment: If it compiled, you already have "downloaded" the style. You might consider posting a screenshot illustrating what you are trying to remove, then post the entire manifest where you have this `android:theme` element so we can confirm that you have it in the correct location.

Comment: Here you go. I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the action bar. Try a `.NoActionBar` theme, such as `Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`.

Comment: It really helped, but in Eclipse it is still there. Is there a posibility how to get rid of it even there? It's very disturbing to imagine that it isn't there when I see it.

Comment: @2rec: "Is there a posibility how to get rid of it even there?" -- not that I am aware of.

Comment: OK, now I'm a bit smarter again. Thank You very much for helping.